# Cannot push 0 to stack in java

Tags: java

I am newbie in Java. I have the problem. This is my code

```
Stack<String> st = new Stack<String>();
int num=9;
while(num > 0){
    st.push(Integer.toString(num%2));
    num/=2;
}
int d=0;
if(!st.isEmpty()){
    d++;
    st.pop();
 }
System.out.println(d);
```

the result is 1.
But correct is 4.
I don't know how to fix it. Sorry if my English is not good. Thankyou

Comment: What are you expecting `d+;` to do?

Comment: sorry d++;//d=d+1;

Comment: Have you stepped through your program with the debugger?

Comment: Hint: how do you expect `d++;` to execute more than once?

Comment: I found out, in while{....} stack has 4 element 1,0,0,1. But  in if{.....} stack has only one element (value 1). I don't know what is problem

Comment: @JonSkeet I want to check how many elements in stack.

Comment: What do you mean by "stack has only one element"? How did you determine that? (It really *does* have a size of 4 before the `if` statement. It has a size of 3 after the `if` statement...)

Comment: @VanLeThanh: No, literally: *how do you expect that line of code to be executed more than once?* Look *very* carefully at what you've written.

Comment: @JonSkeet can you tell me where is my problem??

Comment: I think after while{...} my stack has 4 element. In if {....} I will increase d and pop element until stack is empty.

Comment: _In if {....} I will increase d and pop element until stack is empty_: an `if` statement does not repeat itself - it executes only once. There is no _until stack is empty_ with just a single `if` statement!

Comment: Now that you've been given the answer, it would be a good idea to take a step back and think about how you could have reached it yourself. Did you step through the code in a debugger? What happened? Did you misunderstand how an `if` statement worked, or did you not look at the code closely enough even after hints? This could be a very useful learning experience.

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you so much. I found out my problem. It's if statement.

Comment: @VanLeThanh: Yes, I know it's in the `if` statement. I knew that from the start. I was giving you hints to try to help you spot that for yourself. Again, please don't just move on from this without thinking about it more. Try to work out how you could have figured this out for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is from line 8! When you define **if**, however you have to write **while** loop, NOT **if statement**

Another point is that your stack should be **integer** and its not essential to define stack with **string**

So try it:

```
Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<>();
int num = 9, d = 0;
while(num > 0){
    st.push(num%2);
    num /= 2;
}

while(!st.isEmpty()){
    d++;
    st.pop();
 }
System.out.println(d);
```